# Same DataReceived event handler for a list of SerialPorts

Tags: .net, winforms

I am working on a winforms application. I have a list of SerialPorts, each one listening on a different COM port.

I am planning to add a unique event handler SerialPort.DataReceived for all the SerialPorts. Is this a good design? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure, nothing wrong with that.  And often quite useful since the DataReceived event handler should try to receive an entire "packet" before handing it off to other code that processes the data.  Particularly if you use BeginInvoke to run code on the UI thread.  Different devices usually have different protocols so would need different code in their respective event handlers.  Or different buffers to store partial responses.

Or not and all devices operate the same and sharing the same event handler code will work.  You'd need to cast the *sender* argument to SerialPort to make the proper Read call.  There is little to guess at the appropriate way to go in your question.